# Make my resultbar go away if empty or if not focused

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

As of right now my searchbar wont minimize, I don't really know how to write a code so if it's empty it doesn't display anything. Also I would like to be able to click somewhere else on the screen to make it dissapear. Anyone got any ideas? :)

GIF of problem: https://gyazo.com/518e8a14216b527c003aab7fc32f343c

My input:

```
<input
  className="form-control"
  placeholder="Search CARLDb..."
  value={props.value}
  onChange={(event) => props.setSearchValue(event.target.value)}>
</input>
```

My search list: https://gyazo.com/a7c5b2f2ada0379f2d5b0cee717d7d07

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./components.css";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faStar } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import placeholder from './Images/placeholder.jpg'

const image_url = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500";

const SearchList = (props) => {
  
  return (
    <>
        {props.tvShow?.map((movie) => (
            <div key={movie.id} className="search-box">
            <img
              className="search-image"
              src={movie.poster_path === null ? placeholder : image_url + movie.poster_path}
              alt={movie.poster_path}
            />
            <span className="search-span">
              <FontAwesomeIcon id="search-star" icon={faStar} />
              {movie.vote_average}
            </span>
             <a className="search-link" href={`https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/${movie.id}`} target="_blank" rel="nooponer noreferrer">
                <p className="searchp" onClick={()=> props.handleFavouritesClick(movie)}>{movie.title || movie.name}</p>
             </a>
            </div>
          ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default SearchList;
```

CSS:

```
.search-list { /*built with container fluid*/
    position: absolute;
    left: 38%;
    width: 350px;
    display: inline;
    z-index: 99;
    max-height: 40%;
    max-width: 550px;
}

.search-box {
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    height: 75px;
    max-width: 505px;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Please let me know if I should there is any other code you would like to see. I'm a beginner to React and JavaScript.

Thanks! :)

edit: refered to searchbar instead of my results. I would like to keep the searchbar at all times but I want my resultbox to dissapear.

edit2: added navbar.js and app.js

Navbar.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import logo from "../carldb2.png";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./components.css";
import SearchBox from "./SearchBox";
import SearchList from "./SearchList";


const Navbar = (props) => {
  const getSearchRequest = async () => {
    const search_url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=1e08baad3bc3eca3efdd54a0c80111b9&language=en-US&query=${props.searchValue}&page=1&include_adult=false`;

    const response = await fetch(search_url);
    const responseJson = await response.json();

    if (responseJson.results) {
      props.setMovieSearch(responseJson.results.slice(0, 7));
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.searchValue) {
      getSearchRequest();
    }
  }, [props.searchValue]);
  


  return (
    <div>
      <nav className="navbar">
        <div className="nav-center d-flex">
          <Link to="/">
            <img className="logo" src={logo} alt="logo" />
          </Link>
          <SearchBox
            searchValue={props.searchValue}
            setSearchValue={props.setSearchValue}
            />
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div className="container-fluid search-list">
        <SearchList
          tvShow={props.movieSearch}
          handleFavouritesClick={props.addRecentlyViewed}
        />
        <Link to="/search">
          <button className="results" onClick={closeFunction()}>
            <h7 className="results-text">See all results for "{props.searchValue}"</h7>
          </button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

app.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Homepage from "./components/Homepage";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import SearchPage from "./components/SearchPage";

function App() {
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = React.useState("");
  const [movieSearch, setMovieSearch] = React.useState([]);
  const [tvShow, setTVShow] = React.useState([]);
  const [recentlyViewed, setRecentlyViewed] = React.useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const recentlyMovies = [
      ...new Set(
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("recently-watched"))
      ),
    ];

    if (recentlyMovies) {
      setRecentlyViewed([...new Set(recentlyMovies.slice(0, 5))]);
    }
  }, []);

  const saveToLocalStorage = (items) => {
    localStorage.setItem("recently-watched", JSON.stringify(items));
  };

  const addRecentlyViewed = (movie) => {
    recentlyViewed.forEach((item) => {
      let index = recentlyViewed.indexOf(item);
      if (item.id === movie.id) {
        recentlyViewed.splice(index, 1);
      }
    });
    const newRecentlyViewed = [movie, ...recentlyViewed];
    setRecentlyViewed([...new Set(newRecentlyViewed)].slice(0, 5));
    saveToLocalStorage(newRecentlyViewed);
  };

  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar
        searchValue={searchValue}
        setSearchValue={setSearchValue}
        addRecentlyViewed={addRecentlyViewed}
        movieSearch={movieSearch}
        setMovieSearch={setMovieSearch}
      />
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={
            <Homepage
              tvShow={tvShow}
              setTVShow={setTVShow}
              addRecentlyViewed={addRecentlyViewed}
              recentlyViewed={recentlyViewed}
              setRecentlyViewed={setRecentlyViewed}
            />
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/search"
          element={
            <SearchPage
              handleFavouritesClick={addRecentlyViewed}
              tvShow={movieSearch}
              setTVShow={setTVShow}
              searchValue={searchValue}
              setSearchValue={setSearchValue}
              addRecentlyViewed={addRecentlyViewed}
            />
          }
        />
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Could you add the code/component where you use the `SearchList`?

Comment: Yes! Sorry for late answer, I'm adding my navbar that references to SearchList but also my app.js that declares some values to my navbar.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Navbar` component you could add some flag to show / hide the `SearchList`

```js
const showList = props.searchValue !== "";

{
  showList ? (
    <div className="container-fluid search-list">
      <SearchList
        tvShow={props.movieSearch}
        handleFavouritesClick={props.addRecentlyViewed}
      />
      <Link to="/search">
        <button className="results" onClick={closeFunction()}>
          <h7 className="results-text">
            See all results for "{props.searchValue}"
          </h7>
        </button>
      </Link>
    </div>
  ) : null;
}
```